# Safari (mac) offers to remember password in https basic auth, never remembers it and never offers it

Tags: safari, password, catalina

our intranet has a login through https basic auth, the https certificate is valid, and Safari offers to remember the password.

Sadly, no matter if I check the checkbox, the password gets never remembered, and is never offered in this login dialog. I would obviously like Safari to save and prefill this password (as the user profile is password protected and encrypted anyway).

The full flow is like this:

- I go to jira.ourcompany.eu (where Jira, issue tracking system is installed)
- it redirects to auth.ourcompany.eu where this browser auth dialog is presented
- after confirming, it redirects me back to eg. Jira

This lasts at least since Mojave, now happens in Catalina.

Any advice?

[image]

Comment: have you add a password manually in Safari and checked it ?

Comment: Depending on the auth server they are running, they can disallow saving of passwords.  We did this with our Exchange server and there's even methods to do this in HTML:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality/37292424#37292424

Comment: @Allan: Thanks, but this is not HTML, this is browser's built-in window and I think there is no way for server to tell 'don't save the password' as it's pretty old RFC ...

Comment: The point with HTML that I'm making is there are *still* ways to force/trick your browser and password managers to not save passwords.  As far as the RFC goes, just because it's old doesn't mean it's not adhered to.  Does your password manager work everywhere else?  If so, its not an Apple or Safari issue.